# Rails Nested Resources with :member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I've got something like this in my routes.rb:

```
map.resources :retailers, :has_one => [:invite_code]
map.resources :invite_codes, :member => {:redeem => :get}
```

and it isn't generating a route that I would expect:

```
http://localhost:3000/retailers/1/invite_code/redeem
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To nest resources, use a block like this:

```
map.resources :retailers do |r|
  r.resource :invite_code, :member => { :redeem => :get }
end
```